# Create function to see if date range equals a month or part month

Tags: php

I'm creating a function to check whether 2 dates equal a full month or part of a month.

I'm trying with this inside my if statement:

```
$result["from_date"] = $_GET["from_date"];
$result["to_date"] = $_GET["to_date"];

$start = strtotime($result["from_date"]);
$stop = strtotime($result["to_date"]);
$diff = ($stop - $start); //Diff in seconds
$timespan = ($diff / 86400) + 1;
echo 'timespan - '.$timespan.'<br>';

if(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, ChangeDateFormat($result["from_date"], 'm'), ChangeDateFormat($result["from_date"], 'Y')) == $timespan) {
    return true;
}
```

I've used the dates 2018-10-01 and 2018-10-31 which is returning the timespan as 31.041666666667 meaning its returning true in the above if.

I have also tried the dates 2018-08-01 and 2018-08-30 which does not return true, so thats working correctly.

I'ts just October that is playing up and  I cannot work out why.

Comment: What if the user types 2018-01-15 -> 2018-02-15? I'm not sure I understand what problem you are trying to solve. Can you perhaps explain what this is needed for?

Comment: Regarding your question, why is it only October? I'm quite sure March will be causing the same issue. Both months have one hour more or less than the other, and you calculate in seconds which means your code is affected.

Comment: @Andreas ah yes, you are correct with March too! Basically its a billing routine and reads in data from suppliers itemised bills and generates bills for customers. So to work out pricing i need to know whether the date range is a full month or part month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in comments this is due to daylight savings.
You can use DateTime to calculate the number of days between to dates (and add one).

```
$result["from_date"] = "2018-10-01";
$result["to_date"] = "2018-10-31";

$start = new DateTime($result["from_date"]);
$stop = new DateTime($result["to_date"]);

$diff = $stop->diff($start)->format("%a") +1;

echo 'timespan - '.$diff.' days<br>';
```